# Selenium + Java + WebDriver: Determine if WebElement is PARTIALLY obscured

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

Our company is using Selenium for the purposes of automating test cases for our websites. We have recently discovered an issue with our site where some WebElements are only partially visible on-screen (part of it is hidden by another page); furthermore, we are not implementing a scroll bar to be able to view such an element because the WebElement being hidden is not expected behaviour.

I understand that the method WebElement.isDisplayed() can be used to determine if a WebElement is currently visible on the current page. But, this method will return true even if the WebElement is even partially visible. What should be done to determine if an element is only PARTIALLY visible, and not fully visible?

The example in question looks like this. The "(change)" text is visible and thus isDisplayed() will return true; we require a custom method that will return "true" if and only if the WebElement is partially obscured.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: first of all what's your goal? are you trying to click on partially visible element and failing? or are you trying to see if there are any partially hidden elements? Also can you show some html code, rather than a picture?

Comment: Hi Kiril,

1) We are trying to see if there are any partially hidden elements. Perhaps it would be clearer to state that we would like to develop a method that returns true if the element is fully visible, and false if the element is partially visible or invisible.

2) Unfortunately I am working on web automation as opposed to being a web developer so I do not have access to the HTML.

Comment: Anybody with the browser has access to HTML code via View Page Source, or Developer Tools in the browser.